# Problem with installing SAP NETWEAVER on Linux

Tags: linux, abap, opensuse, netweaver

I'm having trouble installing SAP Netweaver 7.50 SP2, I'm installing on Linux openSUSE 15.0 on a VM. After the commands for installation:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

it accuses the following error:

```
The hostname you have chosen is either configured on a loopback device 
or not active on this server, please check your configuration and hostname
selection. If you are confident about your choice of hostname, start the
install script with -s flag to skip the hostname check.
```

Has anyone ever had this problem solved?

Comment: Are you sure it's `./intall.sh` and not `./install.sh`?

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Which VM, and which installation procedure do you follow?

Comment: I'm using ./install.sh 
The VM is the Oracle Virtual Box

Answer (score 1):

If you're following this [7.50 SP2 installation procedure](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/03/sap-nw-as-abap-7.50-sp2-developer-edition-to-download-consise-installation-guide/), did you **follow** the indicated **prerequisites** or use one of the **4 install options**, and if not can you explain **why**?

Moreover, why don't you install the more recent [7.52 SP1](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/09/13/as-abap-752-sp01-developer-edition-to-download/) which doesn't have these prerequisites and install options?

All the next lines are taken from the 7.50 SP2 guide :

[prerequisite 1] Network configuration of the SAP host operating system:

- The officially supported setup requires a static IP address for the hostname used for the SAP installation. Using DHCP is possible for this developer edition, but be aware of potential consequences. If our installation cannot ping the hostname specified when installing, the installation and startup of the SAP system will fail. Make sure that the hostname specified during installation fulfills SAP requirements, most importantly that it does not exceed 13 characters length and also needs to survive subsequent reboots.

[prerequisite 2] Firewall:

- Deactivate the firewall.

We provide you with several installation options:

- ./install.sh – installs the Developer Edition in dark mode, the installer will configure the SAP system for usage of the physical hostname
- ./install.sh -g– will present you a SAPINST GUI allowing you to modify certain system parameters
- ./install.sh -h – allows you to specify your own hostname to be used by the SAP system
- ./install.sh -s – allows you to skip the hostname check

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.
I followed the same steps, but it did not work. I have the prerequisites. I'll try with this other version to see if it works.

Comment: I followed some of these tips, such as: root the application and install with ./install.sh -s. He started the installation, after some time, accused this error:
SAPCAR: checksum error in /tmp/swpm/JAVA/750/J2EEINSTALL.SDA (error 12). No such file or directory ./install.sh: line 330: ./sapinst: No such file or directory Installation of NPL failed, please check logifiles in / tmp / sapinst_instdir for possible root cause.